# How to AJAX video upload in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, python-3.x

Ok, so I have already posted about this, I am now attempting to isolate the issue..

I am trying to simply submit a form and have an alert appear when that is successful (just to verify my code works). I am new to Jquery/JS. When I have my code commented out the uncommented code works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $myForm = $('.form')
    $myForm.addClass('site-yellow')

    $('.form').on('submit', function(event){

        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(event.target)
        var formData = new FormData(form[4]);
                alert("Video done!");

//        $.ajax({
//            type : 'POST',
//            url : "{% url 'videos-upload' %}",
//            data : {
//            data : formData,
//            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
//            }
//            success : function(){
//            }
//        });
    });
});
```

As soon as I uncomment the code the whole thing breaks.. but I cannot seem to figure it out..

**My view:**

```
class VideoUploadView(PermissionRequiredMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    form_class = VideoUploadForm
    success_url = '/videos'
    template_name = 'videos/video_form.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # stuff
            form.save()
            messages.success(self.request, self.success_message)
            return redirect(self.success_url)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

**My HTML:**

```
        <form class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-row mt-4 mb-4">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12 mb-0">
                    {{ form|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row mt-4">
                <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Save Video</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

What do I need to do to get the AJAX request to submit the form?

Comment: What does "The whole thing breaks" looks like?

Comment: Video uploads as normal. No alerts. No new classes get applied. Apologies, I should have been more explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS:

```
$.ajax({ 
type: 'POST', 
url: '{% url "upload-videos" %}', 
enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
processData: false,
contentType: false,
data: new FormData(this) ,
    success: function(data){
    alert('Success')
    }
```

In your views.py, you need to receive the json:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
         print("done")
```

Comment: May I ask why datatype is json? This is a video upload. Is this correct?

Comment: No,it's not ... I just edited my answer ... that should work ..

Comment: Nevermind. I got it to work. What I had to do was change the URL to `form.attr('action'),` since the `form action` was already set in the template. Any advice on where a good place to learn JS/Jquery is?

Comment: Travesty Media on youtube is pretty good ... If you know C or Java, it comes pretty quick ...

Comment: I don't. Just Python. It doesn't seem too hard but I am not very fluent in HTML - hence this issue. I had not realized that it needed the encoding type as I thought the form in the HTML would still handle this. I am assuming the reason the form doesn't handle this anymore is because of the `event.preventDefault()` function. I will read up on it. Thanks again.